# Nvidia Driver Not running on Ubuntu 18.04 with linux kernel 5.4.0-74

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I am having multiple problems getting my Nvidia driver to run on ubuntu 18.04. I currently had a setup working and after a reboot it seems like my nvidia drivers are not running. I tried to factory reset and re-install everything from scratch but had no luck either.

I have dual boot with windows and secure boot disabled.

I have tried multiple options from online and have gotten none to work.

Here are some outputs which may be useful

```
pc@pcUbuntu:~$ whereis nvidia
nvidia: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia /usr/lib/nvidia /usr/share/nvidia /usr/src/nvidia-460.80/nvidia

pc@pcUbuntu:~$ sudo lspci -v | grep -A 10 VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e84 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8708
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at a3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00

pc@pcUbuntu:~$ dkms status
nvidia, 460.80, 5.4.0-74-generic, x86_64: installed

pc@pcUbuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux pcUbuntu 5.4.0-74-generic #83~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 11 16:01:00 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

pc@pcUbuntu:~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is a workaround, not a solution.)

As TorqueNoFriction mentioned on another forum, he found out that booting while having a monitor connected using display port will cause the boot-up to fail. Booting while having monitors connected using HDMI will work. I have confirmed this on my own system.

Also, you can connect and use monitors using display port after boot up.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the 470 driver from the Ubuntu Nvidia testing PPA fixed the issue for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:albertomilone/nvidia-testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
```

Then reboot.

Other people ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/nt0t0r/frustrated_with_nvidia_breaking_drivers/h0qc0sm/)) reported that using the server drivers from the official repositories also work:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450-server
```

or

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460-server
```

Thread on the nvidia forums about this problem:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/465-24-02-page-fault/175782/24